# IOS LAN SAMBA share access

Tags: ios, nas, smb

A Western Digital MyCloud NAS is pinned on a LAN: is there any native IOS 12.X functionality that enables users to discover LAN-SAMBA resources and browse them (like OSX Finder)?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no native functionality included with iOS for that purpose.

You can download an app to get the functionality you describe. For example the free "FE File Explorer: File Manager" app from Skyjos Co.